# Find file names of excel file in sub-folders

Tags: excel, vba

I am extracting file names from sub-folders, the code will successfully extract all file names from the sub-folders. However, I would like to extract the file names of xlsx files only. Please assist. Thanks!

```
Sub Loop_Folders_And_Get_Files()


Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim i, lastrow1 As Integer
    i = 1
    lastrow1 = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To lastrow1
Call GetFiles(Range("C" & i).Value)
Next i


End Sub


Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String)


Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim folder As Object
Set folder = fso.getfolder(path)

Dim subfolder As Object
For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders
    GetFiles (subfolder.path)
Next subfolder

Dim file As Object
For Each file In folder.Files
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = file.path
Next file

Set fso = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set subfolder = Nothing
Set file = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Use the  Workbook.FileFormat. test for = 55 combined with Type property of teh FSO file object

Comment: @SmileyFtW Thanks, where should I edit?

Comment: `for each file` loop

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
Try this, it should work getting all excel files in folder

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles_01()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\VBA Folder")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If Right(oFile.shortName, 4) = ".XLS" Then
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next oFile

End Sub
```

**Solution 2**
Try this, it should work getting all excel ".xlsx" files in folder

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles_02()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\VBA Folder")
i = 1
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'Debug.Print oFile.shortName
    'Debug.Print Right(oFile.Name, Len(oFile.Name) - InStrRev(oFile.Name, "."))
    If Right(oFile.Name, Len(oFile.Name) - InStrRev(oFile.Name, ".")) = "xlsx" Then
        Cells(i, 1) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next oFile

End Sub
```